# How to always use a particular browser for certain URLs

Tags: browser, default-applications

I have two browsers on my device: Chrome and Firefox. I usually use Firefox, but I have to use Chrome for some sites to work around Firefox bugs. All the same, I get bored of having to choose the browser every time I click a link, when it would be simple to teach the computer which sites I want to use with Chrome.

Is there another way to handle links so that I can set up Chrome to open automatically for some websites and Firefox for others, instead of having to choose every time?

Comment: I did search before posting, but the related-questions finder must be more effective :-(